# Pymongo - Is it possible to return dictionary in map values output

Tags: mongodb

I have following mapper and reducer:

```
mapper = Code("""
           function () {
             emit({'a':this.a,'b':this.b}, {'c':this.c,'d':this.d);
           }
           """)

reducer = Code("""
            function (key, values) {
              var i, total_c,total_d = 0;
              for (i in values) {
                total_c += values[i].c;
                total_d += values[i].d;
              }
              return {'c':total_c,'d':total_d};
            }
            """)
```

This is producing NaN for many values. Is it ok to pass dictionary as output from map in values?

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is coming because there are some values which are undefined. If it tries to add undefined to a number, the result is NaN. Generally NaNs in pymongo are due to something going wrong in mongo, not in Python.

Probably worth checking your data.

If you run the above mapper and reducer with the following structure:

```
db.myCollection.mapReduce(mapper, reducer, {query:{$and:[{'c':{$exists:1}}, {'d':{$exists:1}}]}})
```

This should run it only on values that have values and stop the NaNs!